# alternating selection between two different vectors while making sure each selection is larger than the previous

Tags: r

I need to select numbers alternating between two different vectors. First I select the smallest number globally, then depending where the first number came from the next one needs to come from the other vector and be larger than the selection prior.  Meaning at each new selection I have to do two things. 1) the number has to come from the other vector 2) it has to be greater than the last selection.

Example

```
a <- c(4,7,12,24,27,28,37,50,53)
b <- c(10,14,22,32,36,41,45,47,48,51,54,59,63,68)
```

The result I expect is:  The first item in the answer should be the smallest number "4" which came from vector "a", the next one should be from vector "b" and should be larger than 4.  first item in "b" satisfies both conditions.  The third one should be from "a" and be larger than 10.  12 will do...
The complete resulting vector should be

```
c(4,10,12,14,24,32,37,41,50,51,53,54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using an additional vector storing the vector number and `diff` to find a switch in the vector number:

```
a <- c(4,7,12,24,27,28,37,50,53)
b <- c(10,14,22,32,36,41,45,47,48,51,54,59,63,68)

target <- c(4,10,12,14,24,32,37,41,50,51,53,54)

selectNumbers <- function(x, y) {
  vec <- c(x, y)
  ## create an vector containing the index/number of vec
  idx <- rep(1:2, c(length(x), length(y)))

  ## sort both combined vectors by vec
  o <- order(vec)
  sortedVec <- vec[o]
  sortedIdx <- idx[o]

  ## if the diff == 0 the index doesn't change => excluded
  sel <- c(TRUE, diff(sortedIdx) != 0)

  return(sortedVec[sel])
}

identical(selectNumbers(a, b), target)
# TRUE
```

EDIT: I will go through the code line by line:

```
## create a combined vector
vec <- c(a, b)
# [1]  4  7 12 24 27 28 37 50 53 10 14 22 32 36 41 45 47 48 51 54 59 63 68

## create a vector which contains the origin of each number
idx <- rep(1:2, c(length(a), length(b)))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

## now we sort the combined vector because our selected numbers should increase
o <- order(vec)
sortedVec <- vec[o]
# [1]  4  7 10 12 14 22 24 27 28 32 36 37 41 45 47 48 50 51 53 54 59 63 68

## but we have to know which number was in which original vector (a/b)
## that's why we sort our index vector, too
sortedIdx <- idx[o]
# [1] 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2

## now the critical part: we want to select alternatively
## that's why we exclude every consecutive number in sortedIdx
## (means every sortedIdx[i] == sortedIdx[i+1] => diff(sortedIdx[i:(i+1)]) == 0)
diff(sortedIdx)
# [1]  0  1 -1  1  0 -1  0  0  1  0 -1  1  0  0  0 -1  1 -1  1  0  0  0

## because the diff output has a length of n-1 we need to add the first element
## (which should be the global minimum and will be selected always)
sel <- c(TRUE, diff(sortedIdx) != 0)
sel
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [16] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

## now we return only the selected elements
sortedVec[sel]
# [1]  4 10 12 14 24 32 37 41 50 51 53 54
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jilber, I read it several times but I couldn't understand the logic.  Do you mind explaining a little how it worked.  I don't see where it did the comparison to pick the next larger number.  And even the alternating process from one vector to the other wasn't clear.  It works and works well but I don't understand the logic.

Comment: @user2004820: I am not Jilber but see my edit for clarification.

Comment: I got it now, its great lots of thanks.  What I didn't pay attention to is the order function.  Initially I didn't understand what order produced the "o" in our example.  Now I do  many many thanks.